# halting a client server program

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets

I am sorry for the basicness of this question, but I am having an issue here. I have a client-server program. I don't know before hand how many connections will come but they are not infinite. And at the end , after all connections are closed some results are output. But the problem I am having is, accepting connections is in an infinite while loop, how is it stoppedd to output the result.

Thanks

Comment: can  you post the code for the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

you need to have some form of condition to break out of you loop, in your case, a timeout would probably work the best, basically meaning, if you don't get any new clients for x seconds, you stop looking for clients, same goes for any for of connection error.

Anything more requires looking at the code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Handling `EINTR` on error from [`accept(2)`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/accept4.2.html) with terminating the program and hitting `^C` usually works.

Answer (score 0):

You could install a handler for the `SIGTERM` signal which would set a global `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable, and test that variable in your multiplexing loop (probably around `poll` or `select`). Remember that [signal](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) handlers cannot call many functions (only the *async-signal-safe* ones).

Catching nicely `SIGTERM` is expected from most Linux or Posix servers.

You could consider using an event handling library like `libev`, `libevent` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although my background is with Windows NT the function "names" are ones that name generic threading or process functions that should be available in any multi-threading environment.

If the main thread can determine when the child thread in question should terminate it can either do this by having the child thread loop on a boolean - such as "terminate_conditon" - or by terminating the thread throught its handle.

```
// child thread

terminate_condition=FALSE;
while (!terminate_condition)
{
  // accept connections   
}
child_thread_done=TRUE;
// output results
exit_thread ();

// main thread

child_thread_done=FALSE;
child_thread=create_thread (...);

// monitor connections to determine when done

terminate_condition=TRUE;
while (!child_thread_done)
{
  sleep (1);
}
// or maybe output results here?
exit_process ();
```

This controlled termination solution requires that only one thread writes to the child_thread_done boolean and that any other thread only reads.

Or

```
// child thread

while (1)
{
  // accept connections
}

// main thread

child_thread=create_thread (...);

// monitor connections to determine when done

kill_thread (child_thread);
// output results
exit_process ();
```

The second form is messier since it simply kills the child thread. In general it is better to have the child thread perform a controlled termination, especially if it has allocated resources (which become the responsibility of the process as a whole rather than just the allocating thread).

If there are many child threads working with connections a synchronized termination mechanism is necessary: either a struct with as many members as there are child threads (a terminating thread sets its "terminated" boolean to true, terminates and the main thread monitors the struct to make sure all child "terminated" booleans are true before proceeding) or a counter containing the number of child threads operating (when a child is about to terminate it takes exclusive control of the counter via a spinlock, decrements it and frees the lock before terminating: the main thread doesn't do anything before the counter contains zero).